# complex numbers and cube roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

I would like to solve a/b + b/a + 1=0
I thought I could let omega=a/b.
This leads to solutions of the cube roots of unity.
But I cannot isolate a nor b.

Comment: you have one equation and two unknowns

Comment: You can write it as a $2$ degree polynomial and use the standard procedure for solving it. As hinted by the other comment, you will only be able to express $a$ as a function of $b$ (or conversely), unless there are things you did not tell us.

Comment: "But I cannot isolate a nor b."  No.  You can't.  But there's no reason you should think you can.  If we solve for $\omega$ (there will be three possible solutions).  The if $b$ is *anything* other than $0$ and $a = \omega b$ that will be a solution.  So there are infinitely many solutions.